# Conditional variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm missing something, how do I make this work?

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
string loadStartDate = Request.QueryString["sd"] == String.Empty ? now.AddMonths( -14 ).ToShortDateString();
string loadEndDate = Request.QueryString[ "ed" ] == String.Empty ? now.ToShortDateString();
```

Basically when the page loades if sd and/or ed is blank, then fill the date with my pre-defined stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are forgetting a `:` and the part after it.

The conditional operator has three parts:

- predicate (`Request.QueryString["sd"] == String.Empty`)
- true branch
- false branch

You are missing the false branch syntax and value.

I would write it as:

```
string loadStartDate = string.IsNullOrWhitespace(Request.QueryString["sd"])
                       ? now.AddMonths( -14 ).ToShortDateString()
                       : Request.QueryString["sd"];
```

Note:

`string.IsNullOrWhitespace` is new to .NET 4.0, so use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` for prior versions.

Comment: Yup; and `Request.QueryString[]` will return `null` (rather than `String.Empty`) if no value at all was submitted.

Comment: @p.campbell - Indeed... though if a string is needed, one doesn't need to roundtrip. Missed that.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Was wondering what I was missing. Thank you for the through explanation to. :)

Comment: Am I missing a using statement at top?  It is saying 'string' does not contain a definition for 'IsNullOrWhitespace'

Comment: @JamesWilson - I added a note about that... It is a .NET 4.0 addition. Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` instead if not on 4.0 yet.

Comment: @JamesWilson - No problem. I edited the answer and you probably read before I finished the edit.

Comment: Hrm, I thought I was forcing myself to use `.net 4.0 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />` is there another way I need to tell my program to use 4.0?  Sorry for asking another question in this thread.

Comment: Nevermind, I typed it by hand, and it recognized it perfectly.  Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be like:

```
string loadStartDate = Request.QueryString["sd"] == String.Empty ? now.AddMonths
( -14 ).ToShortDateString():SOME OTHER VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for the conditional operator is:

```
condition ? truevalue : falsevalue
```

You are missing the colon and the value for when the conditon is false.

You *can* use the conditional operator for this, but then it gets a little repetetive. Just do like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string loadStartDate = Request.QueryString["sd"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(loadStartDate)) loadStartDate = now.AddMonths(-14).ToShortDateString();
string loadEndDate = Request.QueryString[ "ed" ];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(loadEndDate)) loadEndDate = now.ToShortDateString();
```